# jni convert string to char array

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

Not familiar with c++, can someone help me add `cmd` to the `myStr` array and pass it to the `main()` function, here is what I have so far:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_my_package_JNIActivity_callCmdLine(
    JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring cmd)
{
    const char *nativeString = env->GetStringUTFChars(cmd, 0);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(cmd, nativeString);

    char * myStr [] = {"v", nativeString};

    //int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    main(1, myStr); 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that a string encoded as [_modified_ UTF-8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17265) is "native"? Use [String.GetBytes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()) to encode a "String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, don't release it before you're finished with it.

```
char * nativeString;

{    const char * _nativeString = env->GetStringUTFChars(cmd, 0);
     nativeString = strdup (_nativeString);
     env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(cmd, _nativeString);
}

char * myStr [] = {"v", nativeString};
main(1, myStr); 

free (nativeString);
```

Comment: I get 
warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'

Comment: `JNIEnv` is defined as `typedef const struct JNINativeInterface_ *JNIEnv;` so this example does not compile.

Answer (score 3):

Why not taking advantage of objects to garantee deletion is done automatically...?

```
class ConvertStringHelper
{
public:
    ConvertStringHelper( JNIEnv *env, jstring value )
    {
        m_str = env->GetStringUTFChars(value, 0);
        m_value = &value;
        m_env = env;
    }
    ~ConvertStringHelper()
    {
        m_env->ReleaseStringUTFChars( *m_value, m_str);
    }

    jstring* m_value;
    const char *m_str;
    JNIEnv *m_env;
};
```

Then:

```
    ConvertStringHelper helper( env, cmd );
    const char* nativeStr = helper.m_str;
    // nativeStr is valid in helper's scope and memory will be cleanly released when exiting the scope!
```